# Ошибка: "mime_content_type(): Can only process string or stream arguments"

Tags: php, laravel, mime-type

Хочу сделать распределение файлов при загрузке по различным коллекциям(картинки к картинкам, видео к видео и т.д.). Вот сам метод, с единичным сравнением, для примера:

```
 public function uploadFile(Request $request)
    {
        if($request -> hasFile('file')) {
            $task = Task::find(1);
            if( mime_content_type($request) == 'image/png') {
                $task->addMedia($request->file('file'))->toMediaCollection('images');
            }
        }
    }
```

Нагуглил, что проблема именно в сравнении, но перепробовав все описанные варианты что удалось найти результатов не принесло. Может кто объяснить в чем именно беда -_-

Comment: `mime_content_type($request->file('file'))`

Comment: `mime_content_type` не умеет работать с переменной класса `Request`

Comment: `$request->file->getClientMimeType()` так можете попробовать